# Order in which listeners are called in Firebase Realtime Database when using updateChildren

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that I have two nodes on the database (`nodeA` and `nodeB`) and I have attached two listeners on these nodes:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
rootRef.child(nodeApath).addChildEventListener(listenerA);
rootRef.child(nodeBpath).addValueEventListener(listenerB);
```

I am updating both nodes at the same time using `updateChildren`:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(nodeApath, valueA);
properties.put(nodeBpath, valueB);
rootRef.updateChildren(properties);
```

In this case, which listener gets called first? I know that Firebase is using a single socket connection / pipelining and sends the results in the same order that they are being updated, but in the case of `updateChildren`, multiple nodes are updated at the same time, so how does Firebase handle that?

How can I make sure that a specific listener (e.g. `listenerA`) will get called first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't depend on any ordering of listeners as passed to the Firebase Realtime Database SDK.  If you want predictable ordering, create an aggregate listener that invokes the callbacks in exactly the order you want.  It could be something like this:

```
public class OrderedValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    private ArrayList<ValueEventListener> orderedListeners;
    public OrderedValueEventListener(List<ValueEventListener> listeners) {
        orderedListeners = new ArrayList<>(listeners);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (ValueEventListener listener : orderedListeners) {
            listener.onDataChange(dataSnapshot);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        for (ValueEventListener listener : orderedListeners) {
            listener.onCancelled(databaseError);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of this listener, passing the list of other listeners that you want invoked in order, to the Query or DatabaseReference that you're interested in.

If you're hoping to get ordering between child and value listeners, I don't believe the SDKs give you any guarantees, and the implementation could change at any time, since ordering was never defined in the documentation.